# CSS Table - Mix of Center and Left Alignment in rowspanned table

Tags: html, css, html-table, centering

Here's my current fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UjAQf/106/

- For the Sport, Status, and Result headings and columns, I want to align center.
- For the Pick, Genius, and Genius Credential heading and columns, I want to align left.
- For the "picksHeading," I want to align left.

What's the most-efficient way to do this?

--
Code:

```
<div class="geniusPicks">

    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">

        <thead>
            <tr id="picksHeading">
                <th>Sport</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th colspan="2">Pick</th>
                <th>Genius</th>
                <th>Genius Credential</th>
                <th>Result</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr class="bigGap">
                <td colspan="7"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="pickHeading">
                <td colspan="7">blah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="pickBody">
                <td rowspan="4">plah</td>
                <td rowspan="4">flah</td>
                <td rowspan="4">glah</td>
                <td>vlah</td>
                <td>mlah</td>
                <td>nlah</td>
                <td rowspan="4">jlah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="pickBody">
                <td>clah</td>
                <td>dlah</td>
                <td>xlah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="pickBody">
                <td>plah</td>
                <td>slah</td>
                <td>klah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="pickBody">
                <td>qlah</td>
                <td>wlah</td>
                <td>zlah</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="smallGap">
                <td colspan="7"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="pickHeading">
                <td colspan="7">blah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="pickBody">
                <td rowspan="4">plah</td>
                <td rowspan="4">flah</td>
                <td rowspan="4">glah</td>
                <td>vlah</td>
                <td>mlah</td>
                <td>nlah</td>
                <td rowspan="4">jlah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="pickBody">
                <td>clah</td>
                <td>dlah</td>
                <td>xlah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="pickBody">
                <td>plah</td>
                <td>slah</td>
                <td>klah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="pickBody">
                <td>qlah</td>
                <td>wlah</td>
                <td>zlah</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="smallGap">
                <td colspan="7"></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.geniusPicks {}

.geniusPicks table {width:100%; font-size:12px;}

.geniusPicks table tr#picksHeading {border:1px solid; background-color:red; height:30px;}

.geniusPicks table tr.pickHeading {border:1px solid;}

.geniusPicks table tr.pickBody td {border:1px solid;}

.bigGap td {height:19px;}

.smallGap td {height:10px;}
```

Comment: This is a question and answer forum. What is your non-subjective question? How are we defining efficient? CSS Parsing time? Number of characters used to code the result? Level of warm-fuzziness when looking at the code/result?

Comment: do you mean horizontal alignment for the ones you want to the left?

Comment: Also, what exactly does `vertical-center`, and `vertical-left` mean? They're very ambiguous phrases.

Comment: Do you mean horizontally left and vertically middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can either add classes to the cells you'd like centered or this might work for you,

#### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/gFA4p/)

CSS added:

```
.geniusPicks table th,
.geniusPicks table th+th+th+th+th+th,
.geniusPicks table .pickHeading+tr td,
.geniusPicks table .pickHeading+tr td+td+td+td+td+td+td {
    text-align: center;
}

.geniusPicks table th+th+th,
.geniusPicks table .pickHeading+tr td+td+td {
    text-align: left;
}
```

This CSS makes use of the [Adjacent Sibling Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) in two places

1. `.pickHeading+tr` - this only targets  the cells which come in the row `tr` which is an immediate sibling of the `pickHeading` row - which is your 7 celled row, this means the smaller rows the ones with only 3 celss never get targeted and are left to default to the left
2. `td` - targets every cell

   `td+td+td+td+td+td+td` - targets every cell which has 6 others preceding it (7)

   `td+td+td` - targets every cell which has 2 others preceding it (3,4,5,6,7)

so the last example in #2 above overrules for cells 3 4 5 & 6, but not 7 as the 2nd example above is more specific

It could probably be done with `:nth-child` to but this way is supported by IE7, and needs one less rule!

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out `vertical-center` + `vertical-left` myself.